# Is there a way to forward emails added to a certain folder on Outlook/Exchange?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

The company I am working with has an Exchange server and uses Outlook as a client. What they want to do is automatically forward an email to an inbox if the email is manually placed in a certain folder. Can this be accomplished and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not feasible to automatically forward messages in a folder using the built-in features in Outlook. As an alternative, you may create a quick step to forward the messages when moving it to the certain folder:
[image]

Reference: [Auto-forward mail from folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fb45f4b9-ef94-4cf5-9c51-dffd5541ecad/autoforward-mail-from-folder?forum=outlook)

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well, unless you script something I don't think it's doable automatically